# Removing WYSIWYG editor markup from an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I am getting a string back from my web service (that I need to set in a `UILabel`) that has WYSIWYG editor markup (not *HTML*) such as:

```
[size=3][b]This is an awesome post![/b][/size]
```

I have a method for `NSString` that strips HTML, but I am unsure how to modify that to search for these sort of opening and closing tags.

```
// How can I modify this?
+ (NSString *)stripHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSRange r;
    NSString *s = [html copy];
    while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];

    return s;
}
```

Could someone shed some light on the regex I can use?

Comment: You can try `@"\\[\\/?.*?\\]"` with the `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` option. But it will remove *all strings* in between square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *myText = @"[size=3][b]This is an awesome post![/b][/size]";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\[\\/?.*?\\]" options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:myText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myText length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Just wrap it into a separate method.

Output of a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVGtiV1YzejBFSEk):

```
This is an awesome post!
```

Answer (score 0):

For **HTML Text**, one solution can be as its not 100% but can be effective:

```
NSString *strText = @"[size=3][b]This is an awesome post![/b][/size]";
strText = [strText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[" withString:@"<"];
strText = [strText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"]" withString:@">"];
NSLog(@"%@",strText);
```

When used in UIWebView it looks like below:

[image]